# How to integrate freeradius with kamailio?

Tags: voip, billing, freeradius, kamailio

I have already configured asterisk dispatcher with kamilio now I wants to configure freeradius with kamailio. What are the possible solutions available for VoIP Custom Billing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what you want to do (all AAA-features, or just accounting, etc). You may use radius modules, like [ACC_RADIUS](http://kamailio.org/docs/modules/stable/modules/acc_radius.html) or [MISC_RADIUS](http://kamailio.org/docs/modules/stable/modules/misc_radius.html).

All the modules and their docs are here: http://kamailio.org/docs/modules/stable/

Comment: i wants to use it with AAA

Comment: Try to read this: http://www.kamailio.org/docs/openser-radius-1.0.x.html ; But actually that doc is outdated and in fact, configs for current kamailio version will differ with doc.